# Can't install Prism...?

Tags: installation, prism

Should have been simple but I guess not.. I downloaded the Prism 2.2 source and the Prism Prism 4.0 Drop 3 source and they both do the same thing. I run the installer and click "Yes" to agree to the terms and then it loads but no files are put on my computer.

Anyone?

Comment: I'm aware of at least two different products called "Prism", and there are probably more. Can you clarify?

Comment: This tag is usually reserved for the Prism at http://compositewpf.codeplex.com.  You might be referring to Delphi Prism or Mozilla Prism?  The tags for those are [delphi-prism] and [mozilla-prism].  Changing your tags might yield better results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this issue at the Prism forum at codeplex many times, and it is usually related to the fact that there are some policies in your computer that don't allow vbscripts to run (this usually happens if that's your office's policy).

You should treat the .exe as a .zip file from which you can manually unzip content. Related links below:

- [Installation Issue](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=76453)
- [Setup
  issues with Prism v2.2/v4.0 when a
  non-default program is used to open
  zip files](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Setup%20issues%20with%20Prism%20v2.2%2fv4.0%20when%20a%20non-default%20program%20is%20used%20to%20open%20zip%20files)

I hope this helps people who run into this.

Thanks,
Damian